# Copying file using node.js with the possibility of cancellation

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs-extra

I am implementing a node.js application which copies an array of file paths, into an specific destination.

The method is simple, Let's say I have 10 file paths at the Origin paths, and 1 path as the destination path. so Each From path will be copied to the destination ONE By ONE using **fs.copy** function.

However, as the file array might be large in terms of number and size therefore I am trying to implement a feature which allows user to cancel the operation of copying files and removing whatever has been already copied.

**My question is**, Is it possible to have cancellation operation on fs.copy ? For example how can I stop fs.copy operation while it is trying to copy a 2GB file?

Is/Are there any alternatives besides fs.copy to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just pipe a readsteam to a writestream, and the unpipe and unlink when you want to stop the copy and delete the destination file.

```
var from = fs.createReadStream(fromFilename)
  .pipe(to);
var to = fs.createWriteStream(toFilename)
  .on("unpipe", function() {
    fs.unlink(toFilename); // effectively deletes the file
  });

// triggered by user
from.unpipe(); // stops the copy, triggers the delete
```

Would that work?

Comment: I also did to.destroy(); before fs.unlink() to eliminate the current stream.